# Sorting Hashmap based on value Not sorting properly giving some unexpected output?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, hashmap, comparator

This is my demo.jsp page,

```
<%
        String key = request.getParameter("key");           
        String[] keyArray = key.split(",");           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
            map.put(+i + "", keyArray[i]);               
        }
        CommonFunction cf = new CommonFunction();
        cf.sortByValues(map);
        Set set2 = map.entrySet();
        Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry) iterator2.next();             
            out.println(me2.getValue());
        }
%>
```

Here keyArray contains "`similar`,`rahul`,`hashmap`,`linkedlist`,`demo`,`ab`"; for this i need to sort according to length or according to string starts with character.
and common functions is

```
public class CommonFunction {

public HashMap sortByValues(HashMap map) {
    List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
    // Defined Custom Comparator here
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
        }
    });

    HashMap sortedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        sortedHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedHashMap;
}
}
```

this code working(sorting) fine when i gave eg:`b,c,a,d` showing output `a b c d` but when i gave String as "`similar`,`rahul`,`hashmap`,`linkedlist`,`demo`,`ab" showing output as`linkedlist hashmap rahul similar ab demo` ,so can anybody help me where to change the code.

Comment: I'm sorting based on values and values are String type.you suggested site is sorting value is int type.so i'm taking help.

Comment: Have you read all the answers in the link?